# MS Access - Force Drop Down After Requery

Tags: ms-access, vba, drop-down-menu

It's a simple order... but it doesn't work.  I can get the combo to drop down, OR I can get it to requery, but I cannot get it to requery and drop down in the same function.  When I put these together it only does the requery.  My hunch is that it needs to wait until the query is complete before going on to dropdown, but I'm only guessing.

> Private Sub Combo15_GotFocus()
>
> ' DOES NOT WORK TOGETHER
>
> Me.Combo15.Requery
>
> Me.Combo15.Dropdown
>
> End Sub

How can I make it requery and dropdown successfully?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you do not have some other code that is interfering?

Comment: No other things interfere.  I eliminated every other action.

Comment: Which version of Access? Also, have you compacted and repaired? Decompiled? tried the whole thing in a new, scratch database?

Comment: compacting and repairing didn't work, although it reduced my db from 6MB to 1MB (thanks).

Comment: Is there a way to have the dropdown command wait until the requery is finished?

Comment: How long does the requery take? You can add a delay, but it might annoy the user more than having to click the dropdown arrow.

Comment: The query takes a split second. There are no mousedown/mouseup events used, however it drops down the list while I mouse down and it requeries when I let the mouse up.  After that, it does not drop down as the vba specifies, unless I click the dropdown arrow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8321/discussion-between-remou-and-ben)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chat you say that the subform controls the records for the drop down, so it seems that a subform event would be best to requery the dropdown:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
    Me.Parent.Combo15.Requery
End Sub
```

This should mean that you can now use the focus event to drop down.

Comment: Yeah, good enough.  :)  It's not exactly what I'd prefer because I have to attach that command to several "on exit" controls, but it is a working solution.  Thanks for the idea.